# Translate text from blocks in admin panel

Tags: blocks, admin-panel, translate

[image]

I am translating text in the blocks with by putting text instead of categories word{{trans "Categories"}}, but I have some text with span element and I don't know how to translate them, If anyone can help, I appreciate, see the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will automatically translate all the strings in `block` content if it will match with the translate CSV.

If you have string like
`Hello <span>John Doe</span>, Welcome`

All you need to do is to add the same string in your `i18n` csv file like

`"Hello <span>John Doe</span>, Welcome","Bonjour <span>John Doe</span>, Bienvenue"`